# Resizing a partition vs resizing a filesystem

Tags: filesystems, partition

In a recent interview I was asked how can you resize a partition which is not a part of LVM?

For which I answer you can use `GParted`. Then the interviewer asked me how would you resize (extend) a file system and not the partition?

For which I said you can unmount the filesystem and resize the underlying partition and remount it, but he said I am wront.

I really thought that resizing a partition and resizing a filesystem is the same thing since filesystem sits on top of partition.

Can someone clarify what he meant by resizing the filesystem? I couldn't get my head around it

Comment: Check out the `resize2fs` tool in the case of ext2/3/4 filesystems. Also: https://askubuntu.com/a/115337/158442

Comment: I suspect you will be much better served googling both the terms than waiting for 1 or 2 answers here.

Comment: [Somewhat related question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1302973/194694). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filesystem is on a partition/device/volume/some other container. It has a fixed size, usually the same as the container. You need to extend the filesystem size as well after extending the underlying container.

Comment: If the partition is already resized why resize2fs is required? can you please explain with example. I want to actually see it happening in my centos.
I mean what recreating a parition how can I see my filesystem is not resized and how can i see it effect after running resize2fs

Comment: RedHat documentation has good examples: [How to Resize a Partition using fdisk](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213) and [How to Grow an ext2/3/4 File System with resize2fs](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1196353). If you resize the partition and then mount the filesystem, it should still report the old size (in `du` etc).

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that `resize2fs` is for EXT filesystems. For XFS the proper command is `xfs_growfs`